# Swift - How to attach bar to the top of table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've got a table view which is situated on top of mapview. It looks like that:

[image]

I wonder how to attach some kind of bar on top of the table view so it indicates that the table is scrollable. Something like thin bar with arrow directed up. I don't have appropriate asset at the moment, but I'd like to know how to do that. I failed to find such thread in the forum.

Doing it in storyboard could be tedious since the table view covers all of the area of main view. So I guess it would be easier to do that by programmatic apprach.

Could you suggest how to approach such problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can show them momentarily when the table view shows on the screen with flashScrollIndicators()
check here : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/flashScrollIndicators

Comment: well, I did something like that
self.tableView.reloadData()
self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()

but nothing has changed, maybe should I use it elsewhere, not just after reloading my table view?

Comment: this method only shows the scroll bar when the tableview is first displayed, you can't force it afterwards.
Apple does not provide a scrollbar that stays visible.

Comment: should I paste it in viewDidLoad() then? I tried it and no changes again. But When I load my table, it is empty. After downloading data from json table is reloaded, maybe this is the cause of issue?

Comment: Yes you would typically put this method in the ViewDidLoad()

Comment: Do you think it can dissapear because of reloading the table?

Comment: as i said you can only call this method when your tableview is created/added as a subview
if you think it is not really clear that the are is scrollable, you could simulate a scroll using :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
This way you will have a nice "animation" and it will be clear for the user that the area is scrollable.
You can always create your custom tableview with a component on the left or right that displays the scroll position.

Comment: I'll dive into docs thanks. Do you have maybe some nice link where creating such custom tableview with component is explained?

Comment: I usually create my own components from scratch, and i rely a lot on apple's documentation.
I am sorry i couldn't be of more help.
Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I tried self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators() in other project where table view added as a subview without any reloading later on and still I cannot see any changes. Are you sure this just about pasting the method into viewDidLoad()? Maybe in iOS8 something has changed about it?