# Flash scroll indicators don't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I got my table view on top of a map view. I want to show to user that the tableView is scrollable. Here is my previos thread: [Swift - How to attach bar to the top of table view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251298/swift-how-to-attach-bar-to-the-top-of-table-view)

I tried using

```
self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()
```

in my ViewDidLoad() method but this doesn't change anything, the table view looks exactly the same as before. I read suggestion that it might be caused by reloading tableView and filling it with data, whilst created tableView is empty. Nonetheless I tried pasting the flashScrollIndicators() method in other project where table is created with cells immediately - again no significant difference.

Am I doing something wrong or using the method in wrong place?

Answer (score 9):

If anyone is still fighting with this problem here is my working solution - works on iOS 11. In my case `flashScrollIndicators()` did not work on first invocation of `viewDidAppear(animated:)`. Invoking `flashScrollIndicators()` with a delay will do the trick.

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: (.now() + .milliseconds(500))) {
            self.collectionView.flashScrollIndicators()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You're using the method in the wrong place. In `viewDidLoad`, the view has just finished loading. It hasn't yet been displayed. A safe alternative would be to move the call into your view controller's `viewDidAppear:` method to make sure that you don't attempt to flash the scroll indicator until the view is already on screen.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I cannot see any difference again. How the indicators are supposed to look like? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @DawidCedrych The indicator should look the same as the normal scroll indicator, but using this method, when the view appears on screen it should fade in briefly and then fade back out. If you still aren't seeing it, it's possible that it's being covered by another view, or is done animating by the time you can see it. Can you provide more information about how the table view is added to the view hierarchy?

Comment: Well, I guess I realize this is not what I'm looking for, normal scroll indicator  is the grey vertical bar on the right edge of screen right? Probably I'm looking for something different, as mentioned in my previous thread above, I need a fine way to show that table is scrollable and attaching some kind of a bar to the top of table view would be the best way. So, could you take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251298/swift-how-to-attach-bar-to-the-top-of-table-view ?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()

}
```